# Pass function as argument

Tags: javascript, function, closures

How can I get this function to pass by reference with this code?

```
var Class = function() {
    var callback1;
    var callback2;

    function buildStuff(data, callback) {
        element.onclick = function() {
            doStuff(callback);
        };
    }

    function doStuff(callback) {
        callback();
    }

    return {
        "setCallback1":function(fn) {
            callback1 = fn;
        },
        "setCallback2":function(fn) {
            callback2 = fn;
        },
        //may rebuild with different data, but same callback
        "buildFoo":function(data) {
            buildStuff(data, callback1);
        },
        //may rebuild with different data, but same callback
        "buildBar":function(data) {
            buildStuff(data, callback2);
        }
    };
}

function main() {
    var object = Class();
    object.setCallback1(function() {
        //do stuff
    });
    object.setCallback2(function() {
        //do something else
    });
}
```

When you actually click on the element, `callback` is `undefined`. I would expect it to be the anonymous function I set it to with the `setCallback` function because the user click occurs after I call the `setCallback` function.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the input. I should have mentioned I need to be able to dynamically set what `callback` equals. So, I can't just eliminate the `callback` parameter from `buildStuff`.

EDIT2: Very sorry for the confusion; I realize my example was a bit too out of context to show what I am doing. `buildStuff` is actually a private member function (using the module pattern) that is called repeatedly. Depending on what is being built, it needs a different callback. The callback is actually set outside of the class (well, module pattern class), so it has to be dynamic. I've updated my code, and again, sorry for the bad example.

Comment: yes, please read my edit.

Answer (score 3):

The click handler you create in `buildStuff` creates a closure over the local variables. You pass `callback` to your `buildStuff` function, but at the time you pass it, it's `undefined`. As this shadows the *other* `callback` variable, you always see *this* value of `undefined`, rather than the state of the *other* `callback` variable.

Instead, don't pass a parameter to `buildStuff`, and the closure will be created, and will capture the `callback` variable you want.

```
function buildStuff() {
    element.onclick = function() {
        doStuff(callback);
    };
}
```

Imagine this;

1. Your global variable `callback` *points* to a value (in this case `undefined`).
2. When you `buildStuff` in `main()`, you pass the value pointed to by callback (`undefined`) as a parameter to `buildStuff`
3. Your click handler creates a closure over local variables + other variables in scope (note that the *local* `callback` *shadows* the global `callback`). `callback` in your event handler is now `undefined`.
4. You *then* `setCallback`. `setCallback` changes the value the global `callback` variable points to using the `=` operator. The global `callback` and local `callback` now point to different values, which is why you don't see the `callback` in the event handler update.

   What you want to do in this situation is to change the value pointed to by `callback`, so other variables pointing there also update, but JavaScript doesn't let you do this.

Comment: @tau: r.e. your edit; you can update the value of `callback` using `setCallback` again?.. or do you mean *sometimes* you want to pass a function directly to `buildStuff`?

Comment: whenever i click on that element, `callback` will always be undefined because it built it while `callback` was undefined. i have to be able to change `callback` after building the elements.

Comment: sorry, i might have misread your comment. sometimes `callback` is different depending on when i call the `buildStuff` function, so i cant have `callback` referenced directly in `buildStuff`.

Comment: You mean you repeatedly call `setCallback` with different values, and want the callback called by `buildStuff` to always be the one `callback` was set to when `buildStuff` was initially called?

Comment: very sorry for the confusion, my example was too out of context i realize. please look at my updated code example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you've already called `buildStuff` before `setCallback`.

The contents of `callback` at the time (undefined) will be used.

If you want to call `buildStuff` with different callbacks, just do that, and eliminate the redundant `setCallback`:

```
function buildStuff(callback) {
    element.onclick = function() {
        doStuff(callback);
    };
}

function doStuff(callback) {
    callback();
}

function main() {
    buildStuff(  
      function() {
        //do something
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: I read the edit. Eliminating the parameter to buildStuff is what *lets* the callback be dynamic. Edited my answer so that doStuff() will only ever use the current value of the global `callback` variable.

Comment: thanks, but i need to be able to call `buildStuff` with different callbacks, so i cant reference `callback` directly like that.

Comment: Re-re-edited. If you want different callbacks in play, there's no use having a single global variable.